# Python signalr socket connection to Windows Server

Tags: python, sockets, signalr, windows-server

I was trying to make a socket connection from my python script to my server. I create a basic connection script (in below) and succesfuly make a connection to Windows Server 2016 (ISS version: 10.0.14393.0) . But when I try same script on Windows Server 2019 (ISS version 10.0.17763.1) I got this error:

> Handshake status 400 Bad Request class 'websocket._exceptions.WebSocketBadStatusException'
>   ERROR:SignalRCoreClient:Handshake status 400 Bad Request class 'websocket._exceptions.WebSocketBadStatusException'

What could cause this problem?

Python script:

```
from signalrcore.hub_connection_builder import HubConnectionBuilder

socket_url = 'ws://mysocketurl.com'
def myprint(msg):
    print(msg)
    pass
try:
    print("Starting Connection...")
    hub_connection = HubConnectionBuilder()\
             .with_url(socket_url,
             options={
                   "headers": {
                           "DeviceID": '123123'
                    }
                 })\
                 .with_automatic_reconnect({
                    "type": "raw",
                    "keep_alive_interval": -1,
                    "reconnect_interval": 5
                 }).build()
    hub_connection.on("Connected", myprint)
    hub_connection.start()

except Exception as exc:
    print("Socket stop working. Error:")
    hub_connection.stop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Server Protocol list you would have to add WebSocket Protocol and install it. After this update it worked.

Comment: Hey, so do I understand it correctly, that you have to install this protocol on the server side?

Comment: @JanF. please look into this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/websocket